# CSS - Putting styles on inputs nested in elements?

Tags: html, css

So, dumb question since directions on my assignment is basically word vomit. Literally word vomit. I need to input CSS code for the following code:

```
   <fieldset class=deliveryinfo>
                <legend>Delivery Information:</legend>
                <label for="nameinput">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="nameinput" name="name"><br><br>
                <label for="addressinput">Street Address</label>
                    <input type="text" id="addressinput" name="address"><br><br>
                <label for="cityinput">City</label>
                    <input type="text" id="cityinput" name="city"><br><br>
                <label for="emailinput">Email</label>
                    <input type="text" id="emailinput" name="email"><br><br>
                <label for="phoneinput">Phone</label>
                    <input type="text" id="phoneinput" name="phone"><br><br>
        </fieldset>
```

**For the input/texts tags the directions state:**

*For input elements within the element with the class value deliveryinfo and for the textarea element, create a 1px solid border using the color #ccc, 0.2em of padding on all sides, and set the font size to 1em.
For input elements within the element with the class value deliveryinfo, absolutely position the elements 8em from the left*

**WOULD I just do** something like `.deliveryinfo nameinput {} .deliveryinfo cityinput {}` ....  and continue with the listed styles? Thanks.

Comment: please add `#`  at **nameinputin and cityinput**  it is id `.deliveryinfo nameinput {} .deliveryinfo cityinput {} `

Answer (score 2):

You can make common styles in one and the custom one in another whih makes the code cleaner. Try this

```
    .deliveryinfo input,
    .deliveryinfo textarea {
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        padding: 0.2em;
        font-size: 1em;
    }

    .deliveryinfo input {
        position: absolute;
        margin-left: 8em;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are missing from the "Would I do" portion of your question is the `#` to signify you are referencing the `id` of the tag.

```css
.deliveryinfo #nameinput {
   color: red;
}

.deliveryinfo #addressinput {
   color: purple;
}

.deliveryinfo #cityinput {
   color: orange;
}

.deliveryinfo #emailinput {
   color: blue;
}

.deliveryinfo #phoneinput {
   color: pink;
}
```

```html
   <fieldset class=deliveryinfo>
                <legend>Delivery Information:</legend>
                <label for="nameinput">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="nameinput" name="name"><br><br>
                <label for="addressinput">Street Address</label>
                    <input type="text" id="addressinput" name="address"><br><br>
                <label for="cityinput">City</label>
                    <input type="text" id="cityinput" name="city"><br><br>
                <label for="emailinput">Email</label>
                    <input type="text" id="emailinput" name="email"><br><br>
                <label for="phoneinput">Phone</label>
                    <input type="text" id="phoneinput" name="phone"><br><br>
        </fieldset>
```

Comment: Glad to help :)